# How to find out if the Github Actions event that triggered the current workflow is a new pull request?

Tags: github-actions, building-github-actions, github-actions-workflows

I have a Github Actions workflow that fires on:

```
on:
  pull_request:
    types:
      - synchronize
      - opened
```

that runs my custom action:

```
jobs:
  my_job:
    uses: "org/repo/.github/workflows/main.yml@master"
```

In the action `org/repo` I want to do an additional thing when a pull request is opened, but *not* when it is synchronized. So in `org/repo/.github/workflows/main.yml` I do:

```
- if: ${{ condition }}
  name: Do that additional thing
```

What should be the `condition` to differentiate between a newly open pull request event and a "synchronize" event (pushing new commits etc)? I guess that would involve checking something in `${{ github.event.pull_request }}`, but I couldn't find it in [the documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The condition is:

```
- if: ${{ github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action == 'opened' }}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: sorry but it covers also the "synchronize" case?